# Named range in Data validation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges, google-sheets-data-validation

I am having trouble getting a named range to work in the data-validation criteria selection.

Given that my named range is "ContactRecord" and the rangeid=1234567890, in the data-validation criteria selection it should be able to support named ranges:

For example:

instead of

```
'SheetX'!B60:B70
```

I should be able to use the named range as the reference like:

```
'SheetX'!rangename=ContactRecord
'SheetX'!rangeid=1234567890
```

Is this just not possible in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- when referencing a Named range in Data validation, you don't need to include sheet name:

[image: 0]

Comment: What if the named range is defined in another sheet on the same document?

Comment: Never mind, the named ranges are global throughout the document, so available across all sheets.

Comment: even then it applies the same. see the picture - I created named range in Sheet1 and on Sheet2 I used same named range without sheet reference. yes, they are global...